# Making a 1140px wide header logo in the twenty-ten theme?

Tags: theme-twenty-ten, css, headers, logo

I've created a child theme that is a wide version of twenty-ten, and it is working for the most part.  But I am struggling to make the header logo wider. You can see the work in progress here at http://7d7d.net

The CSS that is not working is (it still shows as 980px):

```
#branding {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1140px;
}
```

I can see that the generated html for the logo div is:

```
<div role="banner" id="branding">
    <img width="940" height="198" alt="" 
     src="http://7d7d.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/cropped-header.jpg">
</div>
```

And that header.php defines the logo like so:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" 
 width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" 
 height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
```

But I can't see where to set `HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH` and `HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT`.

The CSS file is here: http://7d7d.net/wp-content/themes/twenty-ten-wide/style.css

Comment: -1 why? its a perfectly valid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your theme's functions.php, look for this:

```
// The height and width of your custom header. You can hook into the theme's own filters to change these values.
    // Add a filter to twentyten_header_image_width and twentyten_header_image_height to change these values.
    define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_width', 940 ) );
    define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_height', 198 ) );
```

Its best to creat a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), so you don't loose your customization when you next update WP/theme.

Comment: it already is a child theme, with a style.css file only.  I'll try adding a functions.php to the child as well.  But in any case changing that value in the twenty-ten functions.php has worked thanks.